# setState not rerendering in functional react jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Here is what I believe to be all the relevant code for the component I am trying to test.

```
export function Login() {
  console.log("login called");
  // return <h2 data-testid="loading">Loading....</h2>;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [state, setState] = useState<state>({
    pageStatus: PageStatus.Loading,
    email: "",
    password: "",
    displayName: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const authChangeUnsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("onAuthchange");
      if (user) {
        navigate("/home");
        console.log("logged in");
      } else if (state.pageStatus !== PageStatus.SignIn) {
        console.log("set state to signin");
        setState((prevState) => {
          console.log("in setState function");
          return { ...prevState, pageStatus: PageStatus.SignIn };
        });
      }
    });

    return () => {
      authChangeUnsubscribe();
    };
  }, [navigate, state.pageStatus]);

const getControls = () => {
    console.log("get controls");
    if (state.pageStatus === PageStatus.Loading) {
      return <h2 data-testid="loading">Loading....</h2>;
    }
    return (
      <div className={classes.controlsContainer}>
        <div className={classes.textFieldContainer}>
          <TextField
            data-testid="EmailField"
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            value={state.email}
            onChange={emailUpdate}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.pageContainer}>
      {getControls()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My test file is as follows:

```
jest.mock("firebase/auth");

const navigate = jest.fn();

const authChangeCallbacks: Function[] = [];
const unsubscribeMock = jest.fn();

const mockOnAuthStateChanged = (auth: any, onChangeCallback: Function) => {
  console.log("mock onauthstatechanged called");

  authChangeCallbacks.push(onChangeCallback);

  return unsubscribeMock;
};


describe("login page", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const unsubscribeMock = jest.fn();
    (onAuthStateChanged as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(
      mockOnAuthStateChanged,
    );
    
    jest.spyOn(router, "useNavigate").mockImplementation(() => navigate);
    
  });
  it("renders loading before first auth callback", async () => {
    const loginComponent = render(<Login />);
    const loginElement = await loginComponent.findByTestId("loading");
    expect(loginElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("renders login screen when no user returned", async () => {
    const loginComponent = render(<Login />);
    const loginElement = await loginComponent.findByTestId("loading");
    expect(loginElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    console.log("before act");
    await act(() => {
      console.log("in act");
      authChangeCallbacks[0](null);
    });
    console.log("after act");

    const emailField = await loginComponent.findByTestId("EmailField");
    expect(emailField).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

So I am mocking up the onAuthStateChanged function. I store the callback and manually calling with authChangeCallbacks0. My console logs are indicating that this is working as expected.

The end of my console logs are:

```
before act
in act
onAuthchange
set state to signin
in setState function
after act
```

So it is calling the setState function to change the `pageStatus' to` SignIn`.

Then the "act" ends and the "login called" log is not printed again. So it did not call my function component again. I thought that was the point of the act function.

The test fails with

```
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="EmailField"]

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="pageContainer"
        >
          <div />
          <h2
            data-testid="loading"
          >
            Loading....
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

As it never rerendered with the new state.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. I simply needed to reset my authChangeCallbacks after each run.

When I called `authChangeCallbacks[0]();` it was calling the callback from the previous test.

I added:

```
afterEach(() => {
  authChangeCallbacks = [];
});
```

Everything works as expected after that. I could even get rid of all those awaits and make it a synchronous test function.

Creating the minimum reproducible example helped my figure that out. Thanks [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)